# knockoutJS - ajax form submitting twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, form-submit, double-submit-problem

I have a form that's being submitted twice.

I've looked through similar jQuery-related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15823756/jquery-submitting-form-twice) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15823756/jquery-submitting-form-twice) and google groups [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/knockoutjs/UTgZQNR3YgY) but haven't been able to find a solution.

Since I'm new to Knockout.js perhaps I'm missing something obvious? I'd like to understand why it's happening. Here's what I have:

the form:

```
<form data-bind="submit: Save">
 <div class="span11">
@foreach (var prop in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties)
{      
  @Html.Label(prop.PropertyName, new { @class = "attribute-label" })
  @Html.TextBox(prop.PropertyName, "", new { data_bind = "value: " + prop.PropertyName + "" })

}

</div>
<br />
<button type="submit" class="btn" data-bind="enable: IsEnabled">Update                    
</button>
</form>
```

the viewmodel:

```
var viewModel = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));

viewModel.Save = function() {            

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("UpdateEmployee")',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            type: "POST",
            data: ko.toJSON({ employee: viewModel }),

            success: function(result) {
                //...

            },

            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
               //...

            }
        });

    };

    $(function() {

        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

    });
```

Comment: What is the sequence of events that leads to the 2 form submissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the code you've shown us, there is no reason why it would submit twice.  What could be happening is that you have some other code that is called that is explicitly calling the `Save()` function which makes it appear to be submitting twice.

I wrote up a fiddle to mimic what you have shown, it does not have the same problems you are describing.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeff1203/MzSuJ/)

Comment: My mistake. It was another call to the Save() function, just like you mentioned. Unfortunately I missed it when submitting the question - perhaps it could still help someone else in the future. I noticed you changed how the viewmodel is being created in your fiddle - is the way you did it a better practice? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I wouldn't say it is best practice, it's just more self-contained (I've set up some fiddles to act as templates and I have them set up this way). If you have a simple model, there's no need to complicate everything just to follow a strict pattern. I'd say, just do what makes sense, just as long as it's organized and easy to follow.