# Ajax post to sql using node keeps multiplying the data sent

Tags: jquery, mysql, node.js, ajax

I'm trying to learn how to communicate with a database using node.js on the backend, and jQuery ajax on the client side.

I've got the basic post function to work the first time a user submits Data. Howeer, whenever the user submits additional data through the browser, it is send as multiple duplicated rows to the sql database table. Furthermore, each subsequent time a user enters data, the number of multiplicates increases. I can't figure out why this is happening.

**Some background**
I am working with colleagues around the globe to share some laboratory data using mice weights. My aim is for my colleagues to log into the website, submit some basic data for a mouse, and click a button. The page won't reload, and the prior values don't reset, but the user can manually clear the prior values to enter another set of data. This is when the new set of data is multiplied on the post to sql.

Here is my "working" code:

**jQuery to listen for click event**

```
 // *********************************************
// Send Weights reference data to database
// *********************************************
$("#mouse_save").on("submit", function(e){
    //don't reload page
    e.preventDefault();

    //define ajax request data obj
    // Set Weights data object
    let mouseObj = {};

    mouseObj.ga = $('#mouse_age').val();
    mouseObj.weight = $('#mouse_wt').val();
    mouseObj.twin = $('#mouse_type option:selected').data('twin');

// get location data for submission
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://ip-api.com/json",
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(json)
        {
            mouseObj.country = json.countryCode;
            mouseObj.city = json.city;
            mouseObj.state = json.regionName;

        },
        error: function(err)
        {
            console.log("Geolocation Request failed, error= " + err);
        }
    }).done(function(response) {
        //ajax call to save new Weights object in the db when geoloc is done
        $.ajax({
            url: '/weight/add',
            type: 'POST',
            data: mouseObj,
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false
        });
        console.log("Weights data to DB", mouseObj);
    });
});
```

**Node.js backend for POST**

```
// post user's reference data to the database
router.post('/weight/add', (req, res) => {
    if (req.body){
        var data = req.body;
        var data_ga = req.body.ga;
        var data_weight = req.body.weight;
        var data_twin = req.body.twin;
        var data_country = req.body.country;
        var data_state = req.body.state;
        var data_city = req.body.city;
        console.log("Data added to weights DB:", data);

        // insert statment
        let sql = "INSERT INTO hemat.weightref (gestage, weight, twin, country, state, city) VALUES ('"+data_ga+"', '"+data_weight+"', '"+data_twin+"', '"+data_country+"', '"+data_state+"', '"+data_city+"')";

        // execute the insert statment
        connection.query(sql, function (err, results){
            if (err) {
                return console.error(err.message);
            } else {
                // get inserted id
                console.log('Row insert Id:' + results);
            }
        });
        res.end();
    } else {
        res.send("No data posted from client to send to DB");
    }
});
```

**In the database**
You can see the 1st submission works fine, but when the user tries to submit another set of data it is duplicated. If they try a third set, it will be tripled and so on.

[image: MySQL DB sample]

**EDIT TO SHOW CONSOLE LOG DURING 2ND BUTTON CLICK**
I added some console logs before, during and within the form submission process. I've attached the output below. I see the form submit is called only once per click, but on the 2nd (and subsequent clicks) the code block after e.preventDefault (which I used to prevent page reload) is called multiple times.

[image: 2nd button click console log]

I'd appreciate any help to stop the multiple submissions on subsequent button clicks.

Comment: I'm going to guess (without seeing the rest of the code), that you're attaching multiple submit handlers on accident. You doing your submit attach in a document .ready, or is there a chance you could get calling it over and over?

Comment: Yes, my click handler is under a window ready block. Should I put it outside? My best understanding when looking at my node console is that the 2nd, 3rd etc... clicks are calling the post 2x, 3x and so on.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've attached a console.log to my click event and it only fires once per click.

Comment: Either put a `debugger;` statement or a `console.log` above the `$("#mouse_save").on("submit", function(e){` and see if its getting attached more than once.

Comment: I did as you suggested, but I see the form submit code block is is only called once each time. However, on the 2nd and 3rd button clicks, i see the `console.log` inside the `$.ajax -> .done()` block fires twice.

Comment: See edited question above.

Answer (score 0):

After some more stackoverflow digging, I stumbled on this post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/18681588/1837608) which solved the problem for me. I added the following to my client side code block:

```
// *********************************************
// Send Weights reference data to database
// *********************************************
$("#mouse_save").on("submit", function(e){
    //don't reload page
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation(); // added per solution referenced

    //define ajax request data obj
    // Set Weights data object
    let mouseObj = {};

    mouseObj.ga = $('#mouse_age').val();
    mouseObj.weight = $('#mouse_wt').val();
    mouseObj.twin = $('#mouse_type option:selected').data('twin');

// get location data for submission
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://ip-api.com/json",
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(json)
        {
            mouseObj.country = json.countryCode;
            mouseObj.city = json.city;
            mouseObj.state = json.regionName;

        },
        error: function(err)
        {
            console.log("Geolocation Request failed, error= " + err);
        }
    }).done(function(response) {
        //ajax call to save new Weights object in the db when geoloc is done
        $.ajax({
            url: '/weight/add',
            type: 'POST',
            data: mouseObj,
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false
        });
        console.log("Weights data to DB", mouseObj);
    });
return false; // added per solution referenced
});
```